# How to Format Python Code to 'No Wrap' with an extention in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have both Autopep8 and Black Formatter Installed in VS Code. I don't want to wrap python code to new lines. Please provide different ways to do this.

I tried to format this line, So that wrapping will go away.

```
definition_mst_id = self.request.query_params.get(
    'defination_id', None)
```

I tried this:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=200"
]
```

But it gives this error.
`This setting will soon be deprecated. Please use the Autopep8 extension or the Black Formatter extension. Learn more here: https://aka.ms/AAlgvkb.(2)`

Then I tried this:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 1000,
},
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 1000,
"editor.wrappingIndent": "none",
"debug.console.wordWrap": false,
```

But, this is also not working.
When I try Format Selection, I get following error:
`Extension 'autopep8' is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'python'-files`
Which is same for Black.

Comment: Despite the warning, the setting is currently available. What is your desired effect? How do you work with formatting code?   Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **settings.json** should be enough to do what you want.

```
{
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
  },
  "autopep8.args": [
        "--max-line-length",
        "120"
    ]
}
```

`"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"` is deprecated as is does not refer to the autopep8 **extension** but the "bundled" autopep8.